# JDK version mismatch between Intellij project structure and Maven version

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-8

At project structure of Intellij, **the JDK version is selected as 1.8**

At Maven properties also, the **JDK verison had been mention as 1.8**

*But still upon `mvn --install` somehow I get JDK verion as 11*

Unable to understand the behaviour. And how do I make it as 1.8

Project screenshot

[image]

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --get-selections java` will allow you to set the jdk you want (providing it's been installed with your package manager)

Comment: There is a difference between Maven and IntelliJ. To get the correct version on plain command line use the correct `JAVA_HOME` setting ... furthermore I see many things out of date like your Maven version also old plugins versions etc.. I strongly recommend to upgrade to Maven 3.8.4 furthermore upgrade you maven-compiler-plugin and decide which version of Java you like to use to build and what version the target should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and change in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Runner -> JRE to use JDK 8 or even better set the JAVA_HOME to the JDK 8

Answer (score 1):

regarding your personnal configurations :

by buiding in the terminal :
you should get a java 8 jar, as you ask java 8 as target, with a jdk 11 (this is comaptible)

by buiding in Intellij IDEA :
you should get a java 8 jar, as you ask java 8 as target, with a jdk 8 as project structure.